# How to get data to the server from Js fetch ()?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I try to transfer data from js to the server, but I get "null".

My js:

```
async function sort(param) {
        let classList = param.classList;
                    //"DateCreate"     //Ascending
        console.log(param.id + " " + classList[0]);
       let response = await fetch("/Amendment/Sort", {
            method: "POST",
            body: JSON.stringify({ sortValue : param.id, sortType : classList[0]})
        });
        if (response.ok) {
            let responseHtml = await response.text();
            document.getElementsByClassName("result").innerHTML = responseHtml;
            alert("OK");
        } else {
            alert("Error HTTP: " + response.status);
        }
```

In browser:

[image]

Server's method (Controller: Amendment):

```
  [HttpPost]
                                    //null           //null
  public IActionResult Sort(string sortValue, string sortType )
  {
         //*****//
      return PartialView("_TableData", model);
  }
```

Comment: Does it say `response.ok` is `null`?

Comment: @RhaidzsalAli 
I get an error message because my method on the server will not work because it has input parameters - null

Comment: I think the problem is that the method Sort has more than one parameters. Please check this https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2012/may/08/passing-multiple-post-parameters-to-web-api-controller-methods and focus especially on Passing multiple Parameters to a Web API Controller. I could assume that the Controller you have is an ASP.NET MVC Controller, but this is not the a problem, that you will read for this hold true also for this type of controllers.

Comment: @Christos I think this is what I was looking for. Thanks.

Comment: @Дмитрий You are very welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem resides in the way the framework binds the values you post to the parameters of this action method. If you define a class like the following one:

```
public class SortModel
{
    public string SortValue { get; set; }
    public string SortType { get; set; }
}
```

and then use this class as the only parameter of your action method then the framework will bind correctly the posted values.:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Sort(SortModel sortModel)
{
     // Then use 
     //   - sortModel.SortValue
     //   - sortModel.SortType
}
```

For further options, you can read [this](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2012/may/08/passing-multiple-post-parameters-to-web-api-controller-methods).

Answer (score 1):

**Solution 1:**

You need to use the `[FromBody]` attribute as your request body contains `sortValue` and `sortType`.

Also make a class with `sortValue` and `sortType` string properties and in controller action method, use that class as parameter.

**Soluttion 2:**

Instead of putting `sortValue` and `sortType` in body, sending it from url.

```
var url = "/Amendment/Sort?sortValue=" + param.id + "&sortType=" + classList[0];
let response = await fetch(url, {
    method: "POST"
});
```